# How to use NgIf with a string interpolation selector?

Tags: angular

My code is working fine but my desired background style is not being applied. If case 3 of `getLatestSystemMessage` is selected and `isUserOwner` is false, then "Accepted" is printed on the app. However, I want to add a green background if that happens. To achieve this, I thought of using `NgIf` and to pass the text in the string interpolation `{{}}` through it. I'm new to angular so I'm not sure why my code isn't working...how can I achieve this? My code so far is here:

```
getLatestSystemMessage(thread: Thread): string {
        const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);

        const isUserOwner = thread.project.user.id === this.user.id;

        let content = '';

        if (message) {
            switch (message.type) {
                case 1:
                    if (<any>message.content > 0) {
                        content = isUserOwner ?
                            `Offered you $${message.content}` :
                            `You offered $${message.content}`;
                    } else {
                        content = isUserOwner ?
                            `Offered to translate for free` :
                            `You offered to translate for free`;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        'Cancelled offer' :
                        'You cancelled your offer';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        'You accepted the offer' :
                        'Accepted';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        "You accepted another translator's offer" :
                        "Accepted another translator's offer";
                    break;
            }
        }

        return content;
    }
    const statusBg === "Accepted" ? "style="background-color: green"";
    console.log(this.statusBg.nativeElement);
```

Template:

```
<p class="mb-0" *Ngif = "{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}} === ‘Accepted’" "style = background-color:green"><strong>{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you shouldn't have too much logic on the view itself.

I think what you are trying to do qualifies as too much...

You can always create a controller function to do this more complex logic for you

```
<p class="mb-0" *ngIf="isAccepted(thread)" style = "background-color:green"><strong>{{ getLatestSystemMessage(thread) }}</strong></p>
```

and in the controller:

```
 isAccepted(thread) {
  return getLatestSystemMessage(thread) ===  'Accepted';
 }
```

Or if you wish to retain the logic in the view, you could fix-up your code like this the below.

notice that:

- the `ngIf` case was incorrect
- you don't really need interpolation in this case

```
<p class="mb-0" *ngIf = "getLatestSystemMessage(thread) === 'Accepted'" style = "background-color:green"><strong>{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message....says getLatestSystem message is invalid...as for the 2nd solution, it doesn't work too, I'm not sure why  `return getLatestSystemMessage(thread) ===  ‘Accepted’; - error TS1127: Invalid character.`

Comment: I tried with the `"` before the `style` after the `=`, I tried editing your answer but i couldn't

Comment: these little errors with the quotation marks came from the code in your question,  I have just fixed these syntax errors I had carried across to the answer...  Still both solutions resolve the question you asked